# getting a import cannot be resolved error for import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet

Tags: java

Im using eclipse Photon. The code worcked fine on old computer.  When I got a new computer and tried to run the program The following imports are give me a import cannot be resolved error

import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

I'm assuming im missing some jar files.  Could some one tell me what jar files I need and whare i can find them? Also why does it work find on ole computer with same jars being added?

Answer (score 0):

Those two classes are part of Apache HTTP Components which you can access from https://hc.apache.org/index.html.